# Function returning blank string

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This function keeps on returning a blank string.

```
 public String getRandomWord() {
        int id = (int)(Math.random())*(numberOfRows())+1;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select word from words where id="+id+"", null );
        String s = "";
        if (res.moveToFirst())
            s = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("word"));
        res.close();
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: If that is really the case then `res.moveToFirst()` is `false` which means that the result is empty. That is something you can / should / must / have to check using either logging or a debugger.

Comment: Either `res.moveToFirst()` is false, or `res.getString` is returning a blank string.

Comment: Check the braces where you declare `id` ! Regardles what `numberOfRows()` returns id will always be 1! What you want is may be  `int id = (int)(Math.random()*numberOfRows())+1;`

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the returning of a blank string is that `res.moveToFirst()` is `false` (so your SQL query result was empty) and the if-block will never get run, and thus `s` will always keep its initial value of `""`.

The alternative reason could be that the expression is `true`, but `res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("word"))` returns a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a random row (word) then try using :-

```
public String getRandomWord() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select word from words order by random() limit 1", null );
    String s = "";
    if (res.moveToFirst())
        s = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("word"));
    res.close();
    return s;
 }
```

This does assume that there are rows in the table, if there aren't then you'd still get a blank result.